# Rocket Plume Color for RD-180

Tags: plume, rd-180, color

Here is an image of an RD-180 engine firing at the Marshall Space Flight Center, 1998-11-04:
[image]

Here is the launch of the [Solar Dynamics Observatory](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sdo/launch/index.html) 2010-02-11:
[image]

The SDO launched on a ULA Atlas V-401, which also uses RD-180 engines.

**My question is why the plumes have radically different appearances (bluish in the top image, and orange-yellow in the bottom)?**

---

I have a few guesses:

My understanding is that plumes are dominated by atomic emission lines.  In this case, the propellant is LOX + RP-1.  In-principle, if the temperatures were different, the lines could shift in position and relative strength, but the change seems too significant here.

However, I do know that the stoichiometric ratio of fuel/oxidizer is sometimes adjusted for various reasons.  Perhaps the MSFC was running it at a perfect (hottest) ratio to see what the limits are?  This would affect both the relative strengths of emission lines and the temperature.

Another guess is that, especially for static-mounted tests, the engine exhaust is doused in water to prevent the pad from melting.  This introduces water vapor, not present once you're off the pad in a real launch, which emits with a strong blue line if it then cycles back up to the chamber and re-enters the rocket plume.

There's also the camera, which is two decades newer—or perhaps it is deliberately tuned to a different frequency band.  Maybe the image was tonemapped for some reason, or the camera adjusted the color balance from the vastly different lighting condition.

These remain guesses, and they don't seem adequate to explain the discrepancy.

Comment: I'm almost certain the blueness is an artifact of the imaging in the first image rather than the color of the plume itself. The entire image is oddly desaturated and cold.

Comment: I think the camera is the far more boring but more likely answer. Great question format though!